# child "path" fails because "path" is not allowed to be empty

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to post below json by kibana in elastic but getting the following error. Is my json format is correct or this type of request is not supported by kibana.

```
put 
{"index":{"_index":"insights-201806051143","_type":"doc","_id":"63AADB8C-9F84-4B84-90FB-A0E98F2FF927"}}
{"industry":"abc",
"geographiestaxonomysearch":["Americas","North America","United States"]}
```

Below is the error that I am getting:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "child \"path\" fails because [\"path\" is not allowed to be empty]",
  "validation": {
    "source": "query",
    "keys": [
      "path"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a path for your PUT command e.g. `PUT /myIndex`